# Opensearchserver sort by field

Tags: mysql, sorting, search, jdbc

I have indexed data from a MySQL table into OpenSearchServer v1.5.3

I would now like results to be sorted in ascending order based on an integer field called 'site_rank' regardless of the search score. Please will you let me know how I can achieve this, I have attached an image of my current settings.

Thanks.

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the process:

- Edit your query
- Go to the "Sorted fields" panel.
- Add "site_rank" as first ranking field.

You may also add the score in second position, just in case documents shared the same site_rank value.

[image: OpenSearchServer: sort on integer field]

Comment: Thank you for that, after reindexing my data the ranking started working correctly